# git post-receive hook, windows (server and client) want to call python

Tags: python, git, python-3.x, githooks

I'm using Bonobo (a windows git server), I'm new to it, and trying to on commit to origin it fire off a Python script which would be able to:

- find the user that did the last commit
- find the commit message
- send that information to Python

Once it has that data, it's going to post it to Slack.  No problem there.  I have Python that can take in command line arguments and post to Slack.

What I can't figure out is how to write my:

```
post-receive
```

Here is what I have:

```
#!C:/Program Files\ (x86)/SmartGit/git/usr/bin/sh.exe
message=`git log -1`
python D:/DEVELOPMENT/PHX/PYTHON/git_slack/git_slack.py -channel git_test -user python -message $message
```

So I can call python OK, but I can't get bash, well I think it's bash, I'm a Windows guy :( to populate message and then pass it to python.  So '$message' just ends up being blank and my python fails.

If I write:

```
python D:/DEVELOPMENT/PHX/PYTHON/git_slack/git_slack.py -channel git_test -user python -message "here we go"
```

All the python works fine.  I'm just missing something.  If I type:

```
git log -1
```

From bash, I get a nice block of text that I would be happy to pass to Python and I could regex out the data to use it.

I must pass this information to Python and can't simply use bash to post to Slack as Python will do some work with our internal proxies and firewalls that I can't do in bash.

So my question is, what should my post-receive file look like to accomplice the 3 bullet points above.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work!

```
#!C:/Program Files\ (x86)/SmartGit/git/usr/bin/sh.exe
message=`git log -1`
echo $message
python D:/DEVELOPMENT/PHX/PYTHON/git_slack/git_slack.py -channel git_test -user python -message "$message"
```

I simply had to put $message on the Python in double quotes